# Should I migrate from CGI::Fast to something else in light of CGI.pm's deprecated status and how should I do so?

Tags: perl, cgi, fastcgi

I am using `CGI::Fast` to leverage the speed and scalability of FastCGI, and I also CGI.pm's query string parsing.  I do not use CGI.pm's deprecated HTML writing functions.

Stopping the use of CGI.pm is [strongly advised](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/9wfgtf/perl_and_cgi/) in the community, but in my use case, should I also be thinking of migrating away?  And if so, how do I

1) still leverage FastCGI

2) grab query params

...without adopting a framework like Dancer or Mojolicious?

The code I am looking at replacing is just:

```
 while ( $main::cgi = new CGI::Fast ) {
      my $name = $main::cgi->param('name');
 }
```

I am open to using something like `CGI::PSGI` in conjunction with `Plack::Request`, but I couldn't see how to finesse the FastCGI functionality as `CGI::Fast` and `CGI::PSGI` both want to subclass `CGI` for the creation of the object.  And I'd still have CGI.pm in the mix to enable `CGI::Fast`.  Plack seems like a lot to learn to replace what is now a few lines of code.

Comment: This strongly depends on your use case. You say a few lines of code, so you're talking about small scripts?

Comment: The scripts aren't small but the use of CGI is limited to the CGI::Fast capability and the parsing of query params.  I do my own route dispatch, templating with HTML::Template etc., so I already have a framework in those senses.

Comment: CGI::Fast has the same issue as CGI.pm as far as they are concerned: They want you to use a framework instead of dealing with CGI directly. If you think they're right about CGI.pm, you shouldn't use CGI::Fast either

Comment: It might make sense to rewrite your framework to speak PSGI then. It gives you a lot more flexibility for the future. Query parsing works a bit different, but initially you can start with using one of the tools that makes PSGI requests look like CGI to keep your code running. You can then go about to implement an interface that will allow your framework to take PSGI references.

Comment: Obligatory link to [Sawyer X's _CGI.pm must die_ talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKOqtRMT85s).

Comment: Plack::Request is your friend then. That should be all you need. Try this: `plackup -MDDP -MPlack::Request -e '$app = sub { my $env = shift; my $req = Plack::Request->new($env); p $req->query_parameters; return $req->new_response(200)->finalize; }'` and on another terminal, `curl localhost:5000`

Comment: It seems like a bit of a guide is needed. I'll write up an answer with a hands-on guide. In the meantime, also take a look at [`cgi_this`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-CGIThis/bin/cgi_this), a utility I whipped together for testing CGI related questions. It's build from various other PSGI and CGI bits and showcases how simple this stuff really is. [Here's me talking about it](https://youtu.be/j9FS_jDujrA?t=923) at The Perl Conference in Glasgow this year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This neatly illustrates one reason why PSGI is an improvement on CGI (and its related technologies like FastCGI). In CGI-style programs, the code is tightly coupled with the deployment method and when you change the deployment method, you usually need to make quite large changes to the code. With PSGI-style programs, the code is the same no matter how you deploy it.

You haven't shown us any of your code, but you talk about "a few lines of code". So here's the approach I'd take.

1. Rip all FastCGI-specific code out of your program - leaving a pure CGI-style program.
2. You then have a choice. You could use the techniques I describe in [Easy PSGI](https://perlhacks.com/2016/01/easy-psgi/) to convert your program to a pure PSGI program. Or, if that's going to be too much work, use [CGI::PSGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::PSGI) to run your CGI program in a PSGI environment.
3. You now have a PSGI program that you can use in pretty much any web server environment. You can serve it as a CGI program. You can use [Plack::Handler::FCGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Handler::FCGI) to run it under FCGI. Or you can deploy it as a standalone service behind a web proxy (that last option is the one I'd choose).

But any choice you make at step 3 isn't irrevocable. The same code will work in all deployment environments. And, therefore, moving between them is usually pretty simple.

p.s. CGI.pm isn't exactly deprecated. It has been removed from the standard Perl distribution but that's because its use is discouraged.

Comment: "Standalone service behind a web proxy", I wonder what you mean by that exactly.  I think I understand your 3-steps to rewriting my stuff but I think the only FastCGI specific stuff is the request loop itself.  I had to make sure my variables were clear at the end of the loop but not much else is specific to FastCGI, I don't believe.

Comment: @Marcus one of the core features of PSGI/Plack is that it allows you to run without a traditional web server. There are many Plack based web servers written in Perl (and some in XS) that can run completely stand-alone. But you'd still have some sort of traditional web server that proxies the requests and catches static resources.

Comment: @Marcus: I mean that your web application becomes a completely separate service (in the strict Unix meaning of the word) running on a high port number, accepting HTTP requests and returning HTTP responses. And then you configure your "real" web server (often nginx, in my experience) to forward requests that it receives for your app onto the actual service. It's actually a lot simpler than it sounds.

Comment: That all does sound cool!  However, I'm once again daunted, because every time I look at PSGI, this happens.  I can't get started because I can't parse the darn query params without doing.... what?  Can I do this without messing with my web server ports and thinking about a lot of extra stuff?

Comment: @Marcus: You would use [Plack::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Request) to parse the incoming request and extract the parameters.

Comment: See my comment on the question @Marcus. That's all you really need to do to get started.

Comment: I'm going to have to start with Hello, World on up with this stuff.  Do I now have to rename my executables to .psgi?

Comment: @Marcus: What you call your executables is purely a web server configuration issue. It almost certainly doesn't matter.

Comment: @DaveCross Understood.  One last thing.  Let's say I don't have the cycles to rewrite at the moment and continue to use CGI.pm for query string params.  If I make sure I'm scrubbing all my list-context-usage for bad input (per [Lee's security note](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Fetching-the-value-or-values-of-a-single-named-parameter) in the CGI.pm docs) am I ok for now?

Answer (score 4):

This is a short guide to help you get started. I'm going to use CGI, not FastCGI, but it's really the same thing. Just imagine the loop being around the parameter selection.

### A simple CGI

Let's start with a simple CGI program. I will be using [`cgi_this`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-CGIThis/bin/cgi_this) to run it for lack of having a real web server handy.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $q    = CGI->new;
my $name = $q->param('name');

print $q->header;
if ($name) {
  print <<"HTML";
<html><body><h1>Hello, $name</hi></body></html>
HTML
}
else {
  print <<"HTML";
<html><body><form method="GET">
    <label>What's your name? <input type="text" name="name"></label>
</form></body></html>
HTML
}

1;
```

This is *hello.pl*. It needs an executable flag.

### Running the program

You start it with `cgi_this` as follows.

```
$ ls
hello.pl
$ cgi_this
Exporting '.', available at:
   http://127.0.0.1:3000/

Found the following scripts:
    http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello.pl
```

Now you can open it in the browser.

[image: Firefox with CGI program and form]

If you enter a name and submit the form, it will display a greeting.

[image: Firefox with CGI program and greeting]

### Converting to PSGI

All of this is straight-forward. Now let's convert it.

We'll start with a new file named *hello.psgi*. It doesn't really matter if it's called *.psgi*, but this is the convention.

We have to do a couple of steps in order to make it work with the PSGI protocol. We will use [Plack::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Request) to help us do that.

The entire program needs to be wrapped in a `my $app = sub { ... };` call.

```
#!/usr/bin/env plackup
use strict;
use warnings;

use Plack::Request;

my $app = sub {
  my $env = shift;    # this is the Plack environment

  my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);

  my $q    = CGI->new;
  my $name = $q->param('name');

  print $q->header;
  if ($name) {
    print <<"HTML";
<html><body><h1>Hello, $name</hi></body></html>
HTML
  }
  else {
    print <<"HTML";
<html><body><form method="GET">
    <label>What's your name? <input type="text" name="name"></label>
</form></body></html>
HTML
  }
};

# no 1; here, we want it to return $app;
```

Now obviously we haven't loaded CGI, and there's no CGI environment anyway. So next we need to get the parameter. Get rid of the `$q` bit and use the `$req` instead.

```
my $name = $req->parameters->{name};
```

Now run this with `plackup`, then request it at http://localhost:5000.

```
$ plackup hello.psgi
HTTP::Server::PSGI: Accepting connections at http://0:5000/
<html><body><form method="GET">
    <label>What's your name? <input type="text" name="name"></label>
</form></body></html>
Response should be array ref or code ref: 1 at ...
```

BANG! It fails, because we're not done yet. As you can see, it wrote the HTML to STDOUT, but that didn't go to the browser. That's because PSGI passes around references, and your program does not talk directly to STDOUT or STDERR.

It also complains about the missing reference. Let's deal with that first. At the end of the code reference, add this:

```
# prepare the response
my $res = $req->new_response(200);
$res->content_type('text/html');

return $res->finalize;
```

We're asking our Plack::Request to make a new Plack::Response for us, set a content type, and return the finalized (think *immutable*) response to the Plack handler, which will serialise and it to the browser as an actual HTTP response.

Now replace all the `print` statements. Make a new variable `$content` and instead of `print`ing output, concatenate it to that variable. Then hand that to the response.

```
  my $content;
  if ($name) {
    $content .= <<"HTML";
<html><body><h1>Hello, $name</hi></body></html>
HTML
  }
  else {
    $content .= <<"HTML";
<html><body><form method="GET">
    <label>What's your name? <input type="text" name="name"></label>
</form></body></html>
HTML
  }

  # prepare the response
  my $res = $req->new_response(200);
  $res->content_type('text/html');
  $res->body($content);
```

Now restart your app in the terminal and access it again. It will look the same as the CGI.

[image: PSGI version output]

Answer (score 3):

[PSGI](https://plackperl.org/), as referenced by [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives#PSGI/Plack), is the way to go.

Dancer leverages PSGI, but you can [write code using it directly](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack#.psgi-files) without a framework wrapping around it.

You can use [Plack::Handler::FCGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Handler::FCGI) to run a PSGI app via FastCGI.

Comment: This is helpful and I'm starting to wrap my mind around this stuff, a bit.